# Local Storage issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, local-storage

I'm trying to use local storage so that my invites stay on the page when refreshed. How would I go about implementing this into my code. I really don't know where to start and I'm really struggling with it. Please cans someone just show me how to implement this into my code. Ive been creating child elements and appending them to the UL in the HTML.

```
const form = document.getElementById("registrar");
const input = form.querySelector("input");
const mainDiv = document.querySelector(".main");
const ul = document.getElementById("invitedList"); 

const div = document.createElement('div');
const filterLabel = document.createElement('label');
const filterCheckBox = document.createElement('input'); 

filterLabel.textContent = "Hide those who havent responded";
filterCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
div.appendChild(filterLabel);
div.appendChild(filterCheckBox);
mainDiv.insertBefore(div, ul);


/*
This creates a checkbox to see you has confirmed if they are coming
to the event or not.
*/

filterCheckBox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const isChecked = e.target.checked;
  const lis = ul.children;
      if (isChecked) {
            for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i += 1) {
            let li = lis[i]
            if (li.className === 'responded') {
             li.style.display = '';
            } else {
             li.style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
      } else {
          for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i += 1) {
          let li = lis[i]
          li.style.display = '';
          }    
      }
});


/*
This function creates new list items (the invites). 
*/

createLi = (text) => {

  createElement = (elementName, property, value) => {

  const element = document.createElement(elementName);
  element[property] = value;
  return element;
  }

  appendElement = (elementName, property, value) => {
  const element = createElement(elementName, property, value);
  li.appendChild(element);
  return element;
  }

    const li = document.createElement("li");
    appendElement("span", "textContent", text);
    appendElement("label", "textContent", "Confirmed")
    .appendChild(createElement("input", "type", "checkbox"));
    appendElement("button", "textContent", "edit");
    appendElement("button", "textContent", "remove");
    return li;

}   


}

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = input.value;
    input.value = "";
    const li = createLi(text);     
    ul.appendChild(li);
});

ul.addEventListener("change", () => {
   const checkbox = event.target;
   const checked = checkbox.checked;
   const listItem = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;

 if (checked) {
   listItem.className = "responded";
} else {
   listItem.className = "";
}                    
});


          ul.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {

          const button = e.target;
          const li = button.parentNode;
          const ul = li.parentNode;
          const action = button.textContent;
          const nameActions = {
              remove: () => { 
                      ul.removeChild(li);
          },
              edit: () => {
                      const span = li.firstElementChild;
                      const input = document.createElement('input');
                      input.type = 'text';
                      input.value = span.textContent;
                      li.insertBefore(input, span);
                      li.removeChild(span);
                      button.textContent = 'Save'; 
          },
              Save: () => {
          const input = li.firstElementChild;
          const span = document.createElement('span');
          span.textContent = input.value;
          li.insertBefore(span, input);
          li.removeChild(input);
          button.textContent = 'edit';
          }
         }; 


           nameActions[action]();
         }




       });
```

Comment: It will help if you could create a https://codesandbox.io or a https://codepen.io with the example so it will be easy to debug and get the proper context.

Comment: @glrodasz no, that would not help; there's no reason not to use the similar facilities built right in here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: One way is to just store your data using localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) the other way is to pass your data to your URL as parameter that is a lame solution but it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only can give you an idea for this, if you are planning to save any big data to localStorage, you can save your data to string and remake it to JSON object!
Here's an exmaple for saving data set

```
var toSave = [ ];
var whatToSave = (Your invites data List, maybe a "text" var for your code?, organize 
to array or loop for your "UL" tag)

for(var i=0;i<whatToSave.length;i++){
   var obj = [];
   obj[i] = {
   text:whatToSave[i].text,
   data1:whatToSave[i].data1,
   data2:whatToSave[i].data2,
   ...
   }
   toSave.push(obj[i]);
}
var saveToString = JSON.stringify(toSave);
localStorage.setItem('invites', saveToString); //your invite data saved in local 
storage

....
//after refreshing or when you need to use your saved data

var cameBack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('invites'));
//this will return same data again
//and make function to make UL using retured data array
```

you don't really need to for loop and push if you already organized needed data to array, just wrote it to make you understand an idea to save data in localStorage. I don't know if this will help you but get an idea and implement it to your project :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I will give it a try now :)